# Shorten a switch case method

Tags: java

I am looking for a possibility to shorten my method.

It looks like:

```
public static Optional<String> which(int i) {
        switch (i) {
        case 1:
            return Optional.of(_strArray[0]);
        case 2:
            return Optional.of(_strArray[1]);
        case 6:
            if (bool)
                return Optional.of(_strArray[2]);
        case 7:
            if (!bool)
                return Optional.of(_strArray[3]);
        case 9:
            if (bool)
                return Optional.of(_strArray[3]);
        case 123:
            if (!bool)
                return Optional.of(_strArray[4]);
        case 154:
            if (bool)
                return Optional.of(_strArray[4]);
        //... and so on (lot's of cases)
        default: return Optional.empty();
}
```

How can I make the method shorter? Is there any possibility in Java 8?
An idea would be to take a `Map<Integer, Optional<String>>`, but there are no methods to initialize a map in Java 8.

Comment: Note that you should `break` after the `if` cases otherwise the next switch-case will continue executing!

Comment: The return should end the methode, isn't it?

Comment: Not if the `if` condition evaluates to `false`...

Comment: but that would be ok this case.

Comment: "there are no methods to initialize a map in Java 8" what?

Comment: I heard in Java 9 you can use `Map.of(1, "one", 2, "two")` but the `of`-method is not present in Java 8

Comment: But you can still use everything from previous versions.

Comment: You still want to break after each one because variable i can only be one value, so even though values 7 and 9 both return the same value if the boolean is true, the second one will not be processed.  If your aim is speed, then you need to place a break after each case.  If you want the quickest method, however, abandon switch completely and do a series of if... else if ... else if... else (default) and place the most likely hits top-down, no breaks needed.  I can post this as an example using your code if you'd like.

Comment: @Bill Hileman No, thanks, it's not necessary, but thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like "business logic" - real-world cases.

Make it declarative: as data structure / tabular data, maybe later even defined in XML, together with the boolean logic.

Then "interprete" the data.

This allows for logging what decisions where made, what case was selected.
Helpful in explaining program behaviour, because after a while nobody will be very certain on what is right.

Not efficiency is the case here, but clarity. An efficient data structure still can be used. For instance a Map where appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, I realised it with an own data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use guava's [ImmutableMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html):

```
Map<Integer, String> left = ImmutableMap.of(1, "a", 2, "b", 3, "c");
```